# How to Use Google Calendar API without OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, netbeans-8

I wanted to know if there is any way to use google calendar api without using OAuth.
For example only to write in my public calendar from a web application in Net Beans.
I just need to write to my calendars, not in other people's calendars.
Try using Aouth 2.0 but did not work.

Comment: I think there's no possibility to do this, because you have to be logged in a calendar to edit something. What's your problem with OAuth?

Comment: You must be authenticated (and you must authorize use of API) to use the Google Calendar API (how would google know it is you and that your app has permissions to write to the calendar). Maybe it would be more helpful to say what didn't work for you

Answer (score 2):

Except for displaying a public calendar, you'll always need authorization to perform operations on the Calendar API. If you check the [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) page, you'll see immediately that this requires Authorization. Even using [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which bypasses the manual authorization, uses OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I am using java in netbeans. my application is a type of web service, I return some json using jsp. jsp call the function that returns my upcoming events on my calendar. but when I try to authorize nothing happens. this is my code. (I have all the necessary libraries).

```
  public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    Credential credential;

    try {

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = new GoogleClientSecrets();
        GoogleClientSecrets.Details det = new GoogleClientSecrets.Details();
        det.setClientId("my id");
        det.setClientSecret("my secret");
        det.setRedirectUris(Arrays.asList("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
        clientSecrets.setInstalled(det);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =  new      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new                                                  LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        credential = null;
    }

    return credential;
}
```